# Quick Build is taking a long time to load (short document)

Tags: pdf

I haven't been using LaTex since May of this year. Starting grad school and trying to type up a presentation but suddenly it is taking Quick Build a long time to load. I never had this issue before. Even with a 60 page document that included bibliography and references. This is a very simple document, yet it takes over 30 seconds to load, then I have to click it again. Then I have to click on View PDF to finally see my corrections and additions to the document.

Comment: Please copy the LaTeX code from the document into your question text so we can attempt to duplicate the problem. Also, we need to know what editor you are using. The more details you can provide the better.

Comment: The speed of the compilation is predominantly determined by the reading/writing speed of the volume where the document, the tex installation and maybe input data like images are stored. Is the presentation maybe on a slow flash drive or on a disc which is nearly full?